# Xamarin Can't Convert System.Threading.Tasks

Tags: c#, dictionary, xamarin

I am wanting to make a call to a sever, get back a JSON result and return the result to the calling method.  Below is my code which makes the call to the server:

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string,string>> callAjax(string mthd,Dictionary<string,string> values)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://dev.adex-intl.com/adex/mvc/receiving/"+mthd, content);
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Dictionary<string,string> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>((string)responseString);
    return result;
}
```

And this is the code that calls the above method:

```
public void loginPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(badge.Text)) {
            DisplayAlert("Error", "Enter your badge number", "Ok");
        } else {
            IsBusy = true;
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
               { "badgeNumber", badge.Text }
            };
            GlobalMethods globalMethods = new GlobalMethods();
            Dictionary<string,string> results = globalMethods.callAjax("login", parameters);
            var id = results["userid"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

I am getting a compiler error of "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'" on line "Dictionary results = globalMethods.callAjax("login", parameters);"

Comment: Sounds like you need to `await` your call to `globalMethods.callAjax`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`callAjax` is an async method, so you need to use `await` when calling it

```
Dictionary<string,string> results = await globalMethods.callAjax("login", parameters);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks much!